# Comparing Data Sets

Tags: php, mobile

I have 2 database one in web server and one in a mobile phone. any idea on how can i synchronize the data from my web server to a mobile phone for example i change some data on my web server and the local database on phone must get all the data that change.

my idea was to send all the data from the phone to my web server and compare after that return those data that change. the problem is if i use looping for comparing data it will take much time comparing thousand of records so i'm thinking if there is a way i can compare a set of data.

hope my question is clear.

Comment: Add a property `lastModifiedTime` to each record, save the last synchronization's time on the mobile device, query the server for "all data that has changed since <saved sync time>". Make sure deleted records are soft-deleted instead of physically deleted.

Comment: @DCoder thank you for your suggestion but what if i delete data and add new one how do i know it?

Comment: Soft-delete means you should mark the record as `deleted` instead of physically `DELETE`'ing it from the DB. As for brand new data, just set its `lastModifiedTime` to the current time before you save it. This is a broad topic, and it's not possible to describe a fully scalable and conflict-resolution-capable solution in one post, you'll need to do some research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) to do the synchronization.